# Remove title in Toolbar in appcompat-v7

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-appcompat, android-toolbar

The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html) of `Toolbar` says

> If an app uses a logo image it should strongly consider omitting a title and subtitle.

What is the proper way to remove the title?

Comment: where is the problem if you just set it to an empty string? I dont think you got to use a custom layout which just uses a icon. Guess thats overkill?

Comment: @maffelbaffel Nothing wrong with setting an empty string but it feels improper. But yea, using a custom layout would be overkill.

Comment: I had to do: `toolbar.setTitle("");`

Comment: @FerranMaylinch Yes, this is work for me too!
I Use   **toolbar.setTitle(null);**
which result into Application Name as a default title.
so i set **toolbar.setTitle("");** which work fine.

Answer (score 628, accepted):

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

Comment: This answer and the answer by David_E work as from me if called right after calling `setSupportActionBar()`. Choosing this answer because this seems to be the official way to do this according to the official reference: `Set whether an activity title/subtitle should be displayed.`

Comment: i'ts only for toolbar like actionbar, but not for clean toobar!

Comment: How to remove it using style.xml ? Please help me

Comment: Worked for me. You have to use "appcompat_v7:v21" for this to work.

Comment: you have to check if the above will not produce a NullPonterException by doing:         if(getSupportActionBar() !=null) getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

Comment: What about for older versions?

Comment: @rockydgeekgod Write the above line directly; Do not put it in a variable first.

Comment: I would like to question the naming of this function... Display Show....
Whats the difference. Am I setting my Display - and what is this??!?! Shouldn't that then be set Toolbar and then say Show Title... And shouldn't the enabled be removed? Otherwise I would think that calling this function would always enable this?!?.... ?!§?!?!?!?!? :'(

Answer (score 76):

The correct way to hide/change the Toolbar Title is this:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setTitle(null);
```

This because when you call `setSupportActionBar(toolbar);`, then the `getSupportActionBar()` will be responsible of handling everything to the Action Bar, not the toolbar object.

See [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77763)

Comment: setTitle(null) results in the app name becoming the title.. setTitle("") worked for me.

Comment: in xml I added <Toolbar
       app:title=" "  //  title is a space .       Worked

Answer (score 25):

Try this...

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_landing_page); 

    .....

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_landing_page);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    .....

 }
```

Answer (score 21):

The reason for my answer on this is because the most upvoted answer itself failed to solve my problem. I have figured out this problem by doing this.

```
<activity android:name="NAME OF YOUR ACTIVITY"
    android:label="" />
```

Hope this will help others too.

Comment: This is not a good idea. If you have an `<intent-filter>` on that Activity to allow users to open your app by clicking a URL (for example), the disambiguation dialog will not have any title!

Answer (score 10):

Another way to remove the title from your `Toolbar` is to `null` it out like so:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_awesome_toolbar);
toolbar.setTitle(null);
```

Answer (score 6):

this

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    //toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle("");
    toolbar.setSubtitle("");
    //toolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.ic_toolbar);
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Toolbar try below code:

```
toolbar.setTitle("");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 Toolbar actionBar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    actionBar.addView(view);
    setSupportActionBar(actionBar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

take note of this line  `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);`

Comment: actionBar.addView(view); is a custom view i am adding to the toolbar

Answer (score 3):

Just add this attribute to your toolbar

```
app:title=" "
```

Answer (score 2):

**You can use any one of bellow as both works same way:**
`getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);` 
**and** 
`getSupportActionBar().setTitle(null);`

**Where to use:**

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

**Or :**

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar); 
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar); 
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(null);
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to hide title/label of ToolBar 
the following codes:

```
  Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(null);
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont know whether this is the correct way or not but I have changed my style like this.

```
<style name="NoActionBarStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.myToolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle("");
```

Answer (score 1):

if your using default toolbar then you can add this line of code

```
Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Nobody mentioned:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
```

Comment: Read the question carefully before answering,
OP has asked to remove title from toolbar

Answer (score 0):

`toolbar.setTitle(null);`// remove the title

Answer (score 0):

It's obvious, but the `App Theme` selection in design is just for display a draft during layout edition, is not related to real app looking in cell phone. In my case, there is no title bar in design but the title bar was always in cell phone.

I'm starting with Android programming and fight to discover a right solution.

Just change the manifest file (`AndroidManifest.xml`) is not enough because the style need to be predefined is `styles.xml`. Also is useless change the layout files.

All proposed solution in `Java` or `Kotlin` has failed for me. Some of them crash the app.  And if one never (like me) intend to use the title bar in app, the static solution is cleaner.

For me the only solution that works in 2019 (Android Studio 3.4.1) is:

in `styles.xml` (under app/res/values) add the lines:

```
   <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
```

After in `AndroidManifest.xml` (under app/manifests)

Replace

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

by

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
```

Comment: The question asked was to remove the toolbar title, Not the toolbar itself.

Comment: I didn't understand it that way, because it makes no sense to leave an empty bar, but I think you must be right.

Comment: Yes, Sometimes we have action icons on a toolbar. For example "a search icon". So we need the toolbar in that case but we don't want the title.

Comment: I've got it. However, this tip it can be useful for someone. At start, I have some problems with it.

Comment: Sometimes I browse a question in StackOverflow and find some collateral benefit in some answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding an empty string in the `label` of `<application>` *(not `<activity>`)* in `AndroidMenifest.xml`like that -

```
<application
            android:label=""
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <activity
             .
             .
             .
             .
            </activity>
    </application>
```